# How can I manipulate data using python?

Tags: python, csv, import-from-csv

I am working with a lot of data which is in the form of a CSV file. Currently it's in the form of:

```
543,674,345,547,a
788,474,687,290,b
44,567,1,89,c
...
```

I need to convert/manipulate the data to a new file using python which changes it to:

```
a 1:543 2:674 3:345 4:547
b 1:788 2:474 3:687 4:290
c 1:44 2:567 3:1 4:89
...
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not here to have other people do something for you.

Comment: Try writing something yourself and then when it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.

Comment: We'd like to help, but we don't write code for you. We correct mistakes and provide alternative ways of doing something if necessary, but we want to see your effort up front.

Comment: Python has a great `csv` module that provides ways of interacting with CSVs. You can find the documentation at http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html.

Comment: To add to @RocketDonkey's hint: What you're doing is effectively reading data in one CSV dialect, transforming each row, and then writing data to another CSV dialect. So, if you work out how to transform the list `['543', '674', '345', '547', 'a']` into the list `['a', '1:543', '2:674', '3:345', '4:547']`, the rest is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while not the most elegant solution this does what you describe.

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as myFile:
    reader = csv.reader(myFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
            print row[4] + ' 1:' + row[0] + ' 2:' + row[1] + ' 3:' + row[2] + ' 4:' + row[3]
```

OUTPUT:

```
a 1:43 2:674 3:345 4:547
b 1:788 2:474 3:687 4:290
c 1:44 2:567 3:1 4:89
```